# How can I make a child div appear above a css mask in parent div

Tags: css, wordpress, z-index, css-mask

I've applied an svg mask to an mp4 video created using the Gutenberg cover block. The problem is that the wp-block-cover__inner-container text is also masked by the svg but needs to appear above it.

I've tried to use the following answer to solve my issue but I'm not a pro and unable to do so: [How to apply a mask-image only on an element's background and not on its children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62640346/how-to-apply-a-mask-image-only-on-an-elements-background-and-not-on-its-childre/62640695#62640695)

URL: https://net0kitchen.com/393-2

CSS:

```
.waves-video {
mask-repeat: no-repeat;
mask-position: center center;
-webkit-mask-image: url(https://net0kitchen.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/netzerokitchen-–-doughnut-01-1.svg);
-webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
-webkit-mask-position: center center;
}

.doughnut-text {
text-align: center;
padding: 20px;
margin: auto;
background: red;
color: white;
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move mask styles from `.waves-video` to `.wp-block-cover__video-background`

[image: mask on video only]