# CSS mask-image, is possible to show an element "on top" of the mask (without absolute positioning)?

Tags: html, css

I have a container `div` with an SVG `mask-image` applied to it. It works just fine, the `div` has the "shape" of the SVG itself. When I add another element as a child, say a text one (or another `div`), the element is being "cut" (masked) itself. I think this is the normal behavior of the mask.

**Any way to show the child element, despite the mask applied to the parent `div`?** Possibly without using absolute positioning.

https://codepen.io/gremo/pen/vYdRjgo

```
.mask-wave {
  mask-image: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/sun.svg');
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-position: center;
  mask-size: contain;
}
```

[image: mask-image example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about applying applying the background-color and the mask to `.mask-wave::before` and then absolute position and z-index the pseudo element behind your div. Then you can have your masked shape with background colour behind text or whatever.

Seems to be a duplicate of this [How to apply a mask-image only on an element's background and not on its children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62640346/how-to-apply-a-mask-image-only-on-an-elements-background-and-not-on-its-childre)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked very well. Not so obvious!